# Issues with np.log

Tags: python, numpy, natural-logarithm

I have a numpy array which got derived from pandas.
I am trying to do np.log (natural logarithm) on each of its elements and it is giving me the error.

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'`

The array looks something like this.

```
[5.810785984999995 5.666261181666755 5.577470475833309 7.967268425833254
 8.298006562222156 8.974100307777746 8.553072009444406 9.059574381388813
 9.055145143654158 8.770924936944482 8.52566836194444 8.21766430611109]
```

The array came from a pandas dataframe using the following code: (just for reference as per requested in comments)

```
flag = df.iloc[0:12,7].to_numpy()
```

The error is happening when I try

```
print (np.log(flag))
```

However when I try something like

```
a = np.array([1.35,2.49,3.687])
print (np.log(a))
```

It works fine. These are still float datatypes? So I am unable to figure out what the issue is, and how I can remedy it.

At the end of the day I am looking to get the natural logarithm of my array.

Comment: Do you have a float variable called `np` that's shadowing the numpy import? Verify the data type of the variable that's supposed to be a numpy array and/or post the offending code showing where it's throwing the exception.

Comment: @Woodford I do not have a float variable called np. Its basically import numpy as np.

Comment: That's a object dtype array.   Change it to float dtype.

Comment: I don't understand how `np.log()` could have the stated error, when `np.array()` works fine...

Comment: For object dtype arrays, `numpy` tries to do `[x.log() for x in arr]`, That is it tries to apply a `log` method to each element.  That rarely works since few classes implement a log method.  Same for functions like `sin`.  Operators like `+` translate to `x.__add__(y)`, which often works.  `pandas` readily makes columns `object` dtype (without warning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the elements in your array are not of the appropriate data type for the `np.log` function. Although the elements in your array may appear to be floats, they might have a different data type causing the error.

You can try converting the elements in your array explicitly to the float data type using `astype(float)` before applying the log:

```
flag = df.iloc[0:12, 7].to_numpy().astype(float)
np.log(flag)
```

Comment: The problem lies in how numpy applies a function like `log` to each element of an object dtype array.  Math on that kind of array is hit or miss, and this cast it's a miss.